# Load jquery only for smaller screens - on resize and page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I want to use some jquery but only on smaller screens, like mobile, and also when user resizes the browser. If I use resize function the code works only on resize, if I use code on its own, it work only on page load, how to combine the two? (I am using css class rather than checking the window size in my condition as I found it works better)

```
$(window).resize(function(){    
    if ($(".sampleClass").css("float") == "none" ){
        $('#nav').slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Also there is small problem that when the toggle is in this conditional, then it animates constantly and doesn't want to stop. If I just place it without the condition and resize function, it works like a charm. What am I missing here?

```
    if ($(".sampleClass").css("float") == "none" ){
        $('#nav').slideToggle();
    }
```

Comment: `$(window).on("load resize", function() {//do stuff})` ?

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work the same and save a lot of space :) I have problem with toggle on resize though - if I resize window two, three times and click the menu button (.smapleclass in example above) then it stops working completly, if I resize to the full width and come back to small mobile size then it works sometimes again. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

i would call the function twice: 
- when the DOM is fully loaded
- inside a resize function

concerning your animation problem:
just call a new function after the resize event has finished, e.g. 500 ms later.

```
$(function(){

   if ($(".sampleClass").css("float") == "none" ){
       $('#nav').slideToggle();
   }

   var myVar;
   function myNewFunction(){
       if ($(".sampleClass").css("float") == "none" ){
           $('#nav').slideToggle();
       }
  }

  window.onresize = function() {
      clearTimeout(myVar);
      myVar = setTimeout(function() {
          myNewFunction();
      }, 500);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As guest271314 suggests in their comment, you can attach an event handler to multiple events by specifying a space-separated list of event names in your call to `on`. http://api.jquery.com/on/

As far as the repeated animation goes, it's possible that your animation is actually resizing the document view (since it's sliding content into and out of view), which triggers another resize event, which triggers another animation, and so on.

If that's the case, either adjust your layout and animation so that the `slideToggle()` call doesn't resize your content, or consider another solution.

Comment: I started using just `toggle` instead of `slideToggle` which seemed to work better, but now I realised another issue:  - if I resize window two, three times and each time click the menu button (.smapleclass in example above) to toggle the nav  then it stops working completly, if I resize to the full width and come back to small mobile size then it works sometimes again. What can be the issue?

Comment: Those kinds of issues are often the result of you invoking methods in a slightly different order each time, because they rely on timing of asynchronous events. You'll need to be diligent in your code about not assuming a particular invocation order unless you explicitly set it up via callbacks or promises.